# SQL JOIN returning 3 fields with the name 'id'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a SQL query using joins with 3 tables. It actually works fine, but all three tables have a field called 'id', so later when I try to access the id field, it only accesses the one from the last field. The SQL query is as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM professors AS p 
            JOIN schools_professors AS sp 
            ON p.school_id = sp.id
            JOIN schools AS s ON sp.school_id = s.id  WHERE p.first_name LIKE '%".
                $search."%' OR p.last_name LIKE '%".$search.
                "%' LIMIT 0, 10;"
```

now then, the schools, professors, and schools_professors, all have the id column. How do I access the id of professors though? That's the only one I care about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be using `*` in this case but instead manually project the column names and add an `ALIAS` on it. Example,

```
SELECT   ....,
         p.ID AS ProfessorID,
         s.ID AS SchoolID,
FROM     .....
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: It's beign wrapped in PDO and such to prevent injection, the reason I wanted the * is cause I essentially want all but the id's of the second and third tables, that about 50 colums. It would be a pain to have to type all of them to get rid of two columns.

Comment: if you still want to use `*`, then add extra column for the `Professor and SchoolID` example: `SELECT *, p.ID AS ProfessorID, s.ID AS SchoolID FROM...`